# Issue with FireDac (Delphi) when using on other computer

Tags: delphi, firedac

I have made a application on my developement machine. And this runs perfect. But now i copied it over to a other machine and when i run it i get a error [Phys][MySQL]-314. Cannot load vendor Library. Which is odd because when i check the .dll file is really there. I have even made a check in the program that i looks if the libmysql.dll is there and it is there.

Anybody know what the problem can be?

Create a function to check if the mysqllib.dll is present.
Made the same folder structure as on developement machine.

Comment: Perhaps your application makes use of specific entries in FDConnectionsDesf.ini or FDDrivers.ini and those files are either different or not existent on the other system.

Comment: I'm guessing your target machine probably doesn't have necessary database drivers for MySQL installed. I recommend reading through [Deploying on Windows (FireDAC)](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Deploying_on_Windows_(FireDAC)) to learn hot to properly deploy your database based application on target machine.

Comment: I looked through that wiki page.. And indeed that was new to me. Although now have copied all the necessary bpl i still get the exact same error. 

If wonder why there is no FireDAC installable that you can install on other computers to make it work.

Comment: If you wonder why *there is no FireDAC installable*, ask Embarcadero.